# Foundation JS Modal Centering

Tags: jquery, css, zurb-foundation

I'm having a weird issue with Foundations reveal function. Its not centering on my page.

http://landpros.turnpostinteractive.com/LandPros_Results_2.html

If you go to this page and click the link in the main content area that says "my listing" it will show you the modal and it clearly not being in the center of the page. I'd like this to stay in the center of the screen no matter what the browser size it.

Is this possible? I can over ride the css code but I'm confused as to why its not like that by default.

```
<p>  
  <a class="star" href="#"></a> add to <a class="link reveal" data-reveal-id="myModal" href="#">my listing</a><br/>
</p>

<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal ModalCSS">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h1>Add to My Listings</h1>
  </div><!--/modal-header-->
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p class="top">Please login to use our<br/> My Listings feature.</p><br/>
    <p>My Listings allows you to save your proper-<br/>ties for future visits. It is Free! </p>

    <br/><br/>
    <p class="right">
      <a href="#">login</a> | <a href="#">create an account</a>
  </div><!--/modal-body-->
  <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

here is the HTML I'm using.

Comment: It's centered horizontally. Do you want it centered vertically as well? Also, do you want it to always be placed in the center of the window, even when the user scrolls?

Comment: I just figured it out! is position: absolute to the parent div. So you need to put the overlaying div in the outside div so it centers itself properly! Thank you so much for taking the time to take a look at this! Means a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Center align Modal Box Css Here :-

```
#myModal2 {
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            margin: -202px 0px 0px -92px;
           }
```